# Where-Object Error When Passing Get-Content as Variable

Tags: powershell, foreach, get-winevent, getcontent

First, my PS knowledge is very basic, so know that up front.

I'm working on a basic script to search EventIDs in archived .evtx files and kick out "reports". The Where-Object queries are in .txt files stored in .\AuditEvents\ folder. I'm trying to do a ForEach on the .txt files and pass each query to Get-WinEvent.

Here's an example of how the queries appear in the .txt files:
`{($_.ID -eq "11")}`

The script is:

```
$ae = Get-ChildItem .\AuditEvents\

ForEach ($f in $ae) {
    $qs = Get-Content -Path .\AuditEvents\$f
    Get-WinEvent -Path .\AuditReview\*.evtx -MaxEvents 500 | Select-Object TimeCreated, ID, LogName, MachineName, ProviderName, LevelDisplayName, Message | Where-Object $qs | Out-GridView -Title $f.Name
    }
```

This is the error:

```
Where-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilterScript' because it is null.
At C:\Users\######\Desktop\PSAuditReduction\PSAuditReduction.ps1:6 char:177
+ ... e, ProviderName, LevelDisplayName, Message | Where-Object $qs | Out-G ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Comment: Seems to indicate the variable is empty, but it would still be of type *string* and not *scriptblock*. Also, you can supply a much faster filter with the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet: `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='.*evtx';ID=5}`

Comment: The id in the filterhashtable can be an array of values too `ID=5,6,7,8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your symptom implies that `$qs` is `$null`, which in turn implies that file `.\AuditEvents\$f` is empty.

However, even if it had content, you couldn't pass the resulting *string* as-is to the (positionally implied) `-FilterScript` parameter of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) requires a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`).

You must create a script block from the string explicitly, using [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create).

A simplified example:

```bash
# Simulated input using a literal string instead of file input via Get-Content
$qs = '{ 0 -eq $_ % 2 }'  # Sample filter: return $true for even numbers.

# Remove the enclosing { and }, as they are NOT part of the code itself 
# (they are only needed to define script-block *literals* in source code).
# NOTE: If you control the query files, you can simplify them
#       by omitting { and } to begin with, which makes this 
#       -replace operation unnecessary. 
$qs = $qs.Trim() -replace '^\{(.+)\}$', '$1'

# Construct a script block from the string and pass it to Where-Object
1..4 | Where-Object ([scriptblock]::Create($qs)) # -> 2, 4
```

Note:

- Your code assumes that each `.\AuditEvents\$f` file contains just *one* line, and that that line contains valid PowerShell source code suitable for use a `Where-Object` filter.
- Generally, be sure to only load strings that you'll *execute as code* from sources you trust.

---

Taking a step back:

As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) points out, a much faster way to filter event-log entries is by using [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent)'s  `-FilterHashtable` parameter.

This allows you to save [hastable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literals in your query files, which you can read directly into a hashtable with [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile):

```bash
# Create a file with a sample filter.
'@{Path=".\AuditEvents\.*evtx";ID=11}' > sample.txt

# Read the file into a hashtable...
$hash = Import-PowerShellDataFile sample.txt

# ... and pass it to Get-WinEvent
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 500 -FilterHashtable $hash | ...
```